# Overdrive Media App Running On Windows 8 Laptop doesn't want to download content when minimized &/or extremely slow

Tags: windows-8, audio, download

I have run the Overdrive Media forms-based application on Windows XP and Windows 7 and it works quite well once you get it installed.

Now, I'm running the new version on my Windows 8 Laptop (i7 with 8 Gigs ram) with a 30Mbps connection and the program :

1. doesn't want to download when it is minimized.
   **Additional note**: when I switch away and switch back to the app then it warns me -- download failed error -- but then since the app is back on the forefront it starts downloading immediately again like there is no proble)
2. downloads extremely slow
3. eats my bandwidth as it takes up the entire pipe when it does download content. (example: I'm listening to streaming audio and Overdrive eats so much bandwidth the audio keeps pausing -- I can download huge multi-gigabyte files while listening to music and this doesn't happen)

I'm trying to figure out if anyone else has reported this problem and if there is some kind of workaraound to tell it to continue downloading even if the app isn't fullscreened.

The old one was a windows forms-based app and didn't take up the entire screen.
The new one -- Windows 8 app from the Windows store (again running on my windows 8 laptop) takes up the entire screen acting like a pad application even though I'm on a laptop and could do other work while it simply downloads the audio book.

The old one was extremely fast.  The new one is painfully slow and attempts to download multiple parts of the audio at once really making it slower over all.

Has anyone found a workaround to this?
Are there any settings that I can change on Windows 8 to make it work better?

Comment: How can it be extremely slow but also take your entire pipe?  Why don't you just download the desktop application version instead?

Comment: It's as if it keeps doing retries but doesn't successfully pull the data.  As @Ramhound it tries, my streaming music stops and stutters. Meanwhile you can see Overdrive spinning, spinning, retrieving something. On windows 8 you cannot download the desktop app and point it at the source.  The audio files are from my library and whatever method they use to create the link to the source forces the APP version to take over the download.

Comment: I have the desktop Overdrive application installed on my system right now, its certainly possible, I had no problem installing it ( I just ran the installer ).

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1; I can't explain the behavior of the modern hi application, given how buggy the overdrive program already is that simple explaintion is that it's buggy, since most of your complaints are with the performance the simplest solution instead of asking if anyone else has the problem is to use the desktop application since your using a x86 version of a Windows that's a solution but being  sarcastic isn't acceptable!

Comment: Personally I stopped using Stackoverflow because of users like yourself find this community a great deal better, most users, are  not so full of themselfs